# Flutter & Cloud_Firestore : Failed to retrieve data when using 2 "where"s condition

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I tried to retrieve a few data by giving 2 conditions. But I keep on getting exception error. Why is it? Please have a look!

```
void _levelValue() async {
      QuerySnapshot result = await Firestore.instance
          .collection('levels')
          .where("min_point", isLessThanOrEqualTo: monthlyPoint)
          .where("max_point", isGreaterThan: monthlyPoint)
          .getDocuments();
      result.documents.forEach((element) {
        print(element.data);
      });
      //return result;
    }
```

Error Description

> Exception has occurred.
> PlatformException (PlatformException(error, All where filters other than whereEqualTo() must be on the same field. But you have filters on 'min_point' and 'max_point', null))

Please help me. I'm looking forward to hearing from you. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is fairly clear.  It's telling you that you can't have both `isLessThanOrEqualTo` one field and `isGreaterThan` on a different field.  Firestore just doesn't support this, and there are really no easy workarounds.

To quote the [documentation on query limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations):

> Queries can only perform range filters (>, <, etc) on a single field. Queries with range filters on multiple fields are not supported.

Your alternative is to perform two queries, one for each field, then compute the intersection of those queries in your app.